# How to conditionally compile in a autotools project?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I have an autotools project. I wish to exclude some files from the project, if the user configures so during build. For example, if the build is configured with --no-gui , the files related to GUI are not to be included in the build.

1. What is the standard macro for such a flag in autoconf? Something that could be configured with like --disable-gui?
2. How to establish the link between this configure option and automake input files?

I have Calcote's introductory book Autotools here. If you can give pointers as to the macros involved, I can look it up in the book or the net.

Thank you,

Elan.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [the autoconf manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Package-Options), the correct way to do this is with an `--enable-FEATURE` argument to `configure`. That's done using the macro `AC_ARG_ENABLE`. The four argument to `AC_ARG_ENABLE` are, in order, `FEATURE`, `HELP-STRING`, `ACTION-IF-GIVEN`, `ACTION-IF-NOT-GIVEN`. So in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([gui],
  [AS_HELP_STRING([--disable-gui], [Enable GUI support @<:@check@:>@])],
  [:],
  [enable_gui=check])
```

`AS_HELP_STRING` wraps the help string nicely, and the `@<:@` and `@:>@` are [quadrigraphs](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Quadrigraphs) which expand to `[` and `]` in the output of `./configure --help`. Even though I've specified an empty `ACTION-IF-GIVEN`, `configure` will still set `enable_gui` to `yes` or `no`, depending on whether `--enable-gui` or `--disable-gui` (which is an alias for `--enable-gui=no`) was passed.

So the shell variable `$enable_gui` will be either `yes`, `no` or `check`. This is for the benefit of the poor packagers who make the distribution packages, as it's considered poor form to build optional support based only on a check. See the gentoo article on [automagic dependencies](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/qa/automagic.xml), but packagers would prefer for the build to fail than silently not include a wanted feature.

Now, if `$enable_gui` is `yes` or `check`, we want to check for dependencies and fail if we manually enabled the feature. Since I don't know what library your gui depends on, I'm just going to use `pkg-config` to check for `gtk+-2.0`. The four arguments to `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` (provided by the `pkg-config` package) are, in order, `VARIABLE`, `MODULES`, `ACTION-IF-FOUND` and `ACTION-IF-NOT-FOUND`:

```
AS_IF([test "$enable_gui" != "no"],
  [PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GTK],
    [gtk+-2.0],
    [enable_gui=yes],
    [AS_IF([test "$enable_gui" = "yes"],
      [AC_MSG_ERROR([gtk+-2.0 required, but not found.])],
      [enable_gui=no])])])
```

The reason we use `AS_IF` instead of just writing a normal shell `if`-expression is so that `autoconf` expands anything that an enclosed macro might require (here `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` internally depends on macros like `PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG`). You can test that this does the right thing in all cases by doing something like `./configure --enable-gui PKG_CONFIG=/bin/false`.

Anyway, we've now resolved `enable_gui=check` into either `enable_gui=yes` or `enable_gui=no`. Now we have to pass this to `automake`. The macro to use is [AM_CONDITIONAL](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Usage-of-Conditionals). Its arguments are, in order, `CONDITIONAL` (the name used in `Makefile.am`) and `CONDITION` (the shell test to set `CONDITIONAL`):

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([ENABLE_GUI], [test "$enable_gui" = "yes"])
```

Now, we move over to `Makefile.am`, I'm going to assume a simple program with a couple of optional sources:

```
# You probably have something real for these.
AM_CFLAGS =
LDADD =

bin_PROGRAMS = elanprog
elanprog_SOURCES = elanprog.c elanfile.c

if ENABLE_GUI
AM_CFLAGS += $(GTK_CFLAGS)
LDADD += $(GTK_LIBS)
elanprog_SOURCES += elangui.c
endif
```